# How to calculate this complicated limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need your assistance in calculating this limit here:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\log(ex^{4})}{\log(x^{4})}\right)^{\log\left | x \right |}$$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\log(ex^{4})}{\log(x^{4})}\right)^{\log\left | x \right |}
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1+4\log|x|}{4\log|x|}\right)^{\log|x|} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(1+\frac{1/4}{\log|x|}\right)^{\log|x|} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow -\infty}\left(1+\frac{1/4}{n}\right)^n \\
&=& e^{1/4}
\end{array}$$

Comment: What happened to the e ? Does log(e) equals 1 ? I understand that log is on base 10, and ln is base e. I also don't understand why you use absolute value when dropping the exponent, I can't recall an absolute value in the logarithm rules. And my final question is regarding the last step, why is this entire limit equals e powered by 1/4 (and I guess you means x and not n).

Comment: @user3275222: in calculus $\log$ is always to the base $e$ unless some stupid textbook author explicitly mentions otherwise.

Comment: Btw, $n\to - \infty$ and not $n\to\infty$ but answer remains same.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: @user3275222: the last step is justified by the standard limit formula $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}=\lim_{n\to - \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}=e^{x}$$ and in fact one can use the formula as a definition of $e^{x} $ to develop a theory of exponential and logarithmic functions.

Comment: I understand now. Nice solution. Thank you !!